# Attributes in header() function

Tags: php, redirect, header

Is there a way to send some attributes when redirecting with header() function?

I would like to send some error message when redirecting(PHP5).

I know that I could just show error page for a 5 seconds or so and then redirect.
Or redirect with query in link, but that's not the point.

Somethin like this:

```
header('Location: /mvc/index.php', $some_attributes);
```

and how to get them on index page?

Btw, I think that Location can't be relative, am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A URL is a URL. You can pass data in it the same way as any other URL (i.e. encode it in a query string then read them with `$_GET`).

> Btw, I think that Location can't be relative, am I right?

Yes. Most browsers will perform error recovery on relative URIs in location headers (Lynx will do so while flashing a warning at the user), but the specification requires that they be absolute.

Comment: I know that way with query string. Is this the most common way?

Answer (score 2):

You can use it like this

```
header('Location: /mvc/index.php?attr='.$some_attributes);
```

and retrieve it like this in `index.php`

```
echo $_GET['attr'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put the error message in session, redirect, display the error message on the error page and remove it from the session afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

If your **var** is an **Array**:

```
header('Location: /mvc/index.php?'.http_build_query($some_attributes));
```